# How to compare two lists with a while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop, break, raw-input

I'm trying to make a script that takes in an answer and appends it to a new list, then checks to see if the new list is the same as the other list. When these lists are the same, the while loop should break.

**NOTE**: Each question should not repeat.

Here's my **code**:

```
import random 

questions = ['a','b','c','d','e']

answered_q = []

while len(answered_q) < len(questions):
    question = random.choice(questions)
    answered_q.append(question)
    raw_input = str(input(question + ": "))
    if sorted(questions) == sorted(answered_q):
        break
```

When executed I am still getting random questions but the code does not **break** when the lists have the same contents.

**output** :

`['b','c','b,'d','d']`

If anyone can help it would be great!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of "same"? If you mean same _contents_, you should use a set. Your current implementation tests both contents _and_ order.

Comment: Well, if `random.choice` returns the same element multiple times before it does each one once, then the two lists will never be the same. You might want to use a set instead.

Comment: The lists don't appear to be the same. Notice you have two bs in the second list. This is because sometimes `random.choice(questions)` may produce the same result more than once.

Comment: I will try doing `set(list)` I'll let you know what happens!

Comment: If the questions shouldn't repeat, then you need to remove the question that was selected from the list of available choices. There are lots of ways to do that.

Comment: What is the probability of getting equal lists? :)

Comment: @EliKorvigo The probability is extremely high!

Comment: @EliKorvigo Roughly 1/256 (1 in 4 probability 4 times)

Comment: @Delioth That doesn't look "extremely high" to me ;)

Comment: Lol my mistake then! Thanks for the feed back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really want to do is only append to your new list if the element to be added isn't already in there, so add a check for that.

```
while len(answered_q) < len(questions):
    question = random.choice(questions)
    if question not in answered_q:
        answered_q.append(question)
        raw_input = str(input(question + ": "))
        if sorted(questions) == sorted(answered_q):
            break
```

Of course, under this scheme, the loop should end even without the last if-statement because the length of the two lists will be equal by the time the two sorted lists will be equal.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! I just wasn't checking to see if the question was in the right spot nor was I appending the question correctly. Wow the solution was so simple! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So would I even need the if statement at the end in this case?

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! This is why I love stackoverflow, I barely posted the question and in 2 seconds I already had 5 comments lol

Answer (score 1):

For one, you're getting random questions (and thus orderings), but you are comparing to a set ordering `[a,b,c,d]`.

To solve that with your current implementation, use a set - `{ "a", "b", "c", "d" }`

Though personally, I would just `pop` things from one list to the other, looping while `len(questions) > 0`, which guarantees you won't get questions more than once.